# Draws a Xmas tree on the console, using java.util.Scanner to input size, asking about where the spaces go

Tags: java

I've been trying draw a Xmas tree (print to console) by using size which is input from user.

I also have been trying to find out the logic such as **spaces would it take**. Any `hint` for me would be fantastic. Also, this lab requires only one `for` loop and have to call the method write-pattern which I provide below. Thank you so much.

Sorry if the code was too long. It's just to make sure that you guys can understand it.

Here is the output that I should display with input 4:
  [image: Desired Display]

```
for (int i=0; i <=size; i++) {
        writePattern (' ','*',' ', ' ',' ',size -i,i,0,0,0,size+2);
        writePattern (' ','*','*',' ',' ',size -i,i,i,0,0,size+2);
    }
```

This is the wrirePattern that I mentioned above.

```
private void writePattern(char ch1, char ch2, char ch3, char ch4, char ch5, int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int length)
```

{

```
while ((n1 > 0) && (length > 0)) {
    System.out.print(ch1);
    n1--;
    length--;
     }

 while ((n2 > 0) && (length > 0)) {
    System.out.print(ch2);
    n2--;
    length--;
 }

 while ((n3 > 0) && (length > 0)) {
    System.out.print(ch3);
    n3--;
    length--;
 }

 while ((n4 > 0) && (length > 0)) {
    System.out.print(ch4);
    n4--;
    length--;
 }

 while ((n5 > 0) && (length > 0)) {
    System.out.print(ch5);
    n5--;
    length--;
}

System.out.println();   
}
```

This is from another class which uses to give the output:

`drawer.drawXmasTree();
            System.out.println("\n");`;

Comment: Yes. You told us a sample output. What `size` is that? Please place it as text instead in the question. Also, the question is very unclear. `have to call the method write-pattern which I provide below.` implies you want us to write the code for the `write-pattern()` method for you.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my first time asking question so I tried to make it as clear as possible. It's size of 4. I remembered I typed it in. Appreciate your time tho.

Comment: Also, we have little to no description of **how** to print the tree. The spacing in your image is confusing.

Comment: The space comes from another part of this lab. I forgot to cut them out. So basically, the image that I provided above was for the input of 4.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is there any formula given for the inputs given?

Comment: You want to draw `size` rectangles of stars; rectangle #_i_ (1 <= _i_ <= `size`) is _i_ lines high and _2i - 1_  columns wide.

Comment: I'm surprised *you* know the formula for *his* question, but if it works I'll take it.

Comment: There is no formula because I suppose to figure it out by myself but I could not.

Comment: Please `type out the sample output`.

Comment: Please either **A)** Mark my answer correct and close the question or **B)** Tell me that my answer does not answer the question. @Nin

Comment: [And what else to include; I currently see nothing missing from my answer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **2** sections of the output.

There are the `leaves` (top) of the tree, separating the `trunk` of the tree with ? `newline` characters.

**Leaves:**

Starting from the top, you will notice there are `size` spaces before the first asterisk. The line above that will have `size-1`, then the next `size-2`, and so on until the number of spaces becomes `0`.

However, this pattern is incomplete. It will only give you the first asterisk of each line. Notice how (starting from the top again) that there are 0 spaces after the first asterisk, (no second asterisk) 1 space after the second asterisk, and so on, until the last line.

Use this pattern and the leaves may be an easy/easier (hopefully) task.

**Trunk:**

Each asterisk has no spaces after it.

Starting from the top, it prints out `size-1` spaces, and then `1` line containing `1` asterisk. Then it prints out `size-2` spaces, and immediately afterward, `2` lines of `3` asterisks each.

This pattern continues, each time the number of spaces decreasing by `1`, the number of lines printed with this width increases by `2` (one extra width in either direction), and the number of lines there are increases by `1`.

---

Please correct me if I have made a mistake. This answer is purely logic of **how** to print it; this certainly needs to be translated into proper code to function.